# NetBeans giving "could not find localizing bundle" error after deleting development plugin

Tags: java, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

I've been having a problem with NetBeans plugin development. I was writing a plugin and was having some trouble with it, so I deleted the plugin folder and started over again. — It's worth noting at this point that I am using a Module Suite, not just a standalone Module.
That all worked fine, until I tried to test another module from the same suite. When I ran the suite and tried to open `Tools>Plugins` it keeps popping up an error message that said `could not find localizing bundle [path to Bundle.properties]`

My question is this:
How do I go about clearing the cache of the missing modules so I can test in peace again?

Thanks,
-tlf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to fix this is very simple.

1. Open the 'files' tab/window/pane/whatever in NetBeans (or open the project in your file browser of choice).
2. Navigate to your Module.
   **NOTE:** If you are using a Module Suite, navigate to that instead. All further instructions are the same.
3. Open the `build` folder.
4. For precise adjustment, open the `testuserdir` folder, and tweak away.
   To simply reset the test IDE, delete the `testuserdir` entirely because you, like me, have no idea what to tweak to set what you want, then restart NetBeans (yes you have to, sorry), and run your project!

-tlf

<sub>P.S. I want to mention, to prevent confusion, that this question was posted with the "Answer your own question" box checked.</sub>